# The use of Move in Rapidjson

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I wonder difference in rapidjson between the follow two ways, I have already tried to read [rapidjson doc](http://rapidjson.org/) but still confused about it.

```
1. doc.AddMember("tag", tag_str, doc.GetAllocator());
2. doc.AddMember("tag", rapidjson::Value(tag_str).Move(), doc.GetAllocator());
```

I want to know the difference between the two usage, thanks.

Comment: welcome to SO. your question does not contain a question. What are you confused about? Always try to imagine the person who is going to answer your question doesn't know anything about the thoughts you had. Put yourself into others shoes

Comment: thanks, I wonder the difference between the above two way

Answer (score 2):

```
1. doc.AddMember("tag", tag_str, doc.GetAllocator());
```

This adds tag_str to the document by constant reference. So tag_str must outlive the document.

```
2. doc.AddMember("tag", rapidjson::Value(tag_str).Move(), doc.GetAllocator());
```

This copies the tag_str value into a Value object which is then moved into the document.